# Error saying that name 'math' is not defined when trying to use asin()

Tags: python

I have made a Trignometric calculator (Kind of - it only uses the sine ratio as of now) but I can't get it to work right. I get an error that says math is not defined when it's supposed to get the length of the line. Here is my code:

```
    trig = raw_input ('What are you looking for? A) I have the opposite, and I want the        Hypotenuse. ')
    if trig.lower() == 'a':
        ang = raw_input ('Please enter the measure of the angle you have ')
        line = raw_input ('Please enter the length of the opposite! ')
        math.asin (ang)*line
```

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Why are you expecting `math` to be defined?

Answer (score 8):

You need to `import math` before you can use it -- otherwise Python doesn't know what you're talking about.

Once you do that, you'll get another error: your inputs are strings, and you need to convert them to numbers (with `float()`) before you can pass them as arguments to math functions. As [nye17 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10676908/344821), if the user inputs the angle in degrees, you'll also need to convert it to radians before passing it to `asin`.

Answer (score 3):

Corrected version.  Your maths is wrong too, but I'm not doing all your homework ;-)

```
import math
trig = raw_input ('What are you looking for? A) I have the opposite, and I want the Hypotenuse. ')
if trig.lower() == 'a':
    ang = float(raw_input ('Please enter the measure of the angle you have '))
    line = float(raw_input ('Please enter the length of the opposite! '))
    print "answer is", math.asin(ang)*line
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the math module: `import math`